# C#4.0 using static

Tags: c#-4.0

I was given the following task and I am hoping that someone will be able to guide me in the right direction. Currently, we have code compiling in C#6. Due to varying reasons, some of my fellow coworkers are running C#4 and are unable to upgrade to C#6. I have to slightly alter the code so that it compiles for my coworkers.

In c#6, we have the following code:

```
using System;
using static SecGlobal.Constants;
```

with SecGlobal.Constants being:

```
namespace SecGlobal
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string CONST_DB_SERVER = "server name";
        public const string CONST_MAIN_TIME_ZONE = "Eastern Standard Time";
        ... etc
    }
}
```

The issue I run into is that the feature  "using static" is not available in C#4. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace constant references with a fully qualified name. For instance,

```
using System;
using static SecGlobal.Constants;

...
string s = CONST_DB_SERVER;
...
```

Becoming

```
using System;
...
string s = SecGlobal.Constants.CONST_DB_SERVER;
```